# Нахождение количества анаграмм

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте.

Помогите решить задачу на паскале. С клавиатуры вводится слово, состоящее из заглавных латинских букв. Определите, сколько различных анаграмм можно составить из данного слова.

Пример работы программы:

> TRANSPOSITION  // данное слово
> 194594400  // количество анаграмм данного слова!

Заранее спасибо. =)

Кстати,  вот мои наработки:

```
var    
    s, s1: string;    
    i, j, kol, fac, fact, q, res, w: longint;    
begin    
    readln(s);    
    q:= 1;    
    fac:= 1;    
    for i:= 1 to length(s) do    
        begin    
            fac:= fac*i;    
        end;    
    for i:=1 to length(s) do    
        begin    
            kol:= 0;    
            s1:= s[1];    
            for j:= 1 to length(s) do    
                begin    
                    if s1=s[j] then    
                        begin    
                            inc(kol);    
                            delete(s, j, 1);    
                        end;    
                end;    
            fact:= 1;    
            for j:= 1 to kol do    
                begin    
                    q:= q*j;    
                end;    
        end;    
    res:= fac div q;    
    writeln(res);    
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
program anagramm;
function factorial(n:integer):longint;
begin
    if n=0 then factorial:=1 else factorial:=n*factorial(n-1);
    end;
var x:string; g,s,z,p,k:integer;m:real;
begin
writeln('Vvedite slovo dlinoy do 12 simvolov');
readln(x);
p:=length(x);
k:=1;
z:=1;
for s:=1 to (p-1) do
begin
    for g:=s+1 to p do
    begin
        if (x[s]=x[g]) then z:=z+1; 
    end;
end;
m:=(factorial(p))/(factorial(z));
writeln('Chislo anagramm = ',m);
readln;
end.
```

Comment: Попробуйте вот так. Чтобы вставлять код выделите его и нажмите на иконку, где единицы и нули.

Comment: Нет. Не правильно =(

Comment: Кстати, как я понимаю это с другого форума! Спасибо, но я и сам там могу поискать! ;)

Comment: Да, я уже отвечал на подобную задачу не на одном форуме.

Answer (score 1):

В общем мое решение. Правильная математическая формула оказалась в учебнике Виленкина за десятый класс.

```
uses SysUtils;
var  num, denom, fact : Double;
    i, j, len, same, totalsame: integer;
    word: string;
begin
    readln(word);
    len:= length(word);
    denom:= 1;
    totalsame:= 0;
    for i:= 1 to len do 
        if word[i] <> '_' then begin
            fact:= 1;
            same:= 1;
            for j:= i + 1 to len do 
                if word[i] = word[j] then begin
                    same:= same + 1;
                    totalsame:= totalsame + 1;
                    fact:= fact * same;
                    word[j]:= '_';
                end;
            denom:= denom * fact;
        end;{if}
    num:= 1;
    if totalsame = 0 then totalsame:= 1;
    for i:= 2 to len do
        num:= num * i;
    writeln(word, ':', len, ' - ',  totalsame);
    writeln(num / denom);
end.
```

Ответ = `количество_букв! / ( П (количество_встереченных_букв w[i])`! )

Comment: В LongInt полученные числа никак не влезают, поэтому применены переменные типа double.